# File upload in MVC with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

My file upload in MVC was working however I have tried to make the design more bootstrap like by using this example found here:

https://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3

Which gives me the design I want but has now messed up my upload. The post is sent to the controller but when I look the file hasn't actually been sent. On the controller I get

public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) <<< null in here

Here is code from the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Job", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">
                Browse <input type="file" style="display: none;" multiple>
            </span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Send" />

    <h5><span class="label label-warning">@ViewBag.Message</span></h5>
}
```

There is some javascript I have used from that webpage, I think this script is suppose to add the file/s into a file collection? and so that they are sent back. What I see happen is:

1. User selects a photo by clicking browse
2. Selects file
3. Then the name of
   the file is displayed the input box
4. Click send

However when I click send the file is never sent (no error as its not received). Have I missed something obviously here?

It used to work by using:

```
@Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
```

Here is the javascript that I've included:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {

    // We can attach the `fileselect` event to all file inputs on the page
    $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
        var input = $(this),
            numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
            label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
    });

    // We can watch for our custom `fileselect` event like this
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

            var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
                log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

            if( input.length ) {
                input.val(log);
            } else {
                if( log ) alert(log);
            }

        });
    });

});
```

Also worth noting if I include the original file upload control:

```
@Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
```

Then it works as it should, I can't seem to figure it out, my only option might be to go with the original design file upload design...

Comment: You cannot set the value of a file input using javascript (it can only be set by the user selecting a file)

Comment: Also your file input indicates multiple file uploads enabled - but you're passing single `HttpPostedFileBase` object, use `public ActionResult UploadFile(List<HttpPostedFileBase> file)` instead. Can you show any related JS scripts related to file upload?

Comment: hi there, thanks for your response the javascript related is here https://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3 do we think that's the problem as the author seems to think his method works

Comment: @MartinCooke. You need to show your code in your question (not a link to someone else's code)

Comment: Have now added in the javascript :)